# Requisição $http não retorna valores

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando montar uma factory para varias requisições, porém o resultado é sempre `undefined`, o que pode estar errado?

Meu angularjs:

```
(function(){
angular
.module("store", ['ui.bootstrap', "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize"])
.controller("homeCtrl", appController)
.factory('httpService', function($http, $q){

    return {
        getData: getDataHandler
    };

    function getDataHandler(url, data){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {'p': data}
        }).then(handlerSuccess, handlerError);
    };

    function handlerSuccess(response){
        return response.data
    }

    function handlerError(response){
        if(!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message){
            return $q.reject('Ops! Aconteceu algo errado.');
        }
        return $q.reject(response.data.message);
    }
});


function appController($scope, $http, httpService){

    console.info(httpService.getData('php/list.php', null));

    $scope.page = httpService.getData('php/list.php', null); 

}
})();
```

Minha lista de exemplo:

```
<?php
$p = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))->p;

$list = '{
    "title": "Aulas",
    "categorias": [{ 
        "nome": "Matemática",
        "subcategorias": [
            "Algebra",
            "Estatística",
            "Cálculo I",
            "Cálculo II",
            "Cálculo III",
            "Geometria Analítica"
        ]
    },{ 
        "nome": "Engenharia",
        "subcategorias": [
            "Materiais",
            "Estrutural",
            "Elétrica",
            "Química"
        ]
    }]
}';

 print($list);
```

Comment: O que você está mandando na variável data?

Comment: a variavel data pode ou não conter valores, é indiferente

Comment: Tentei também com service, visto que trabalham da mesma forma, o resultado é o mesmo.